# write "Section 1" instead of "1.1"

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, enumerate, sections-paragraphs

How can I write section 1 instead of 1.1 in my report and show it on
Table of Contents
this is the only solution I have founded but this do not show section on table of content

```
\section*{Section 1 :ABC}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete, as you don't say which document class you're using.

I'll assume, however, that you're using `report` or `book`, i.e. a class that has chapters. Since a section must have a unique number, this number is prefixed with the chapter number.

So you might want to use the `article` class, which has no chapter, so section numbers have no prefix.

Comment: You should mentioned, that for numbered section title command is `\section{ABC}`.  It take care for correct numbering of sections. Anyway, +1 for nice answer.

Comment: I am using a report class because I am writing my end of studies  project report

Comment: Although the class is called "report", you don't have to use it if it doesn't fit your needs. In particular, what LaTeX calls a "report" is a multi-chapter document, hence the double numbering of sections. On the other hand, the "article" class has no chapter, but it has parts, so it might be more appropriate for a project report.

Comment: thanks , so how can i change the class into article because i am using a template latex

Comment: It depends on your template, but if you can change it, look for the line at the top containing `\documentclass` and change its argument. Depending on the template, it might cause trouble. If it does, you'll have to revert the change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what it is that you want to end up with. You are using the `report` class which has `\chapter` and `\section` commands with the section numbers preceeded by the chapter number. Perhaps you should use the `article` class, like

```
% \documentclass{report} %% orginal class usage
\documentclass{article}  %% now using article class
```

However, in the `report` (or `book`) class you can remove the chapter numbers from the section numbers as shown below.

```
% secnumprob.tex  SE 643700
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{By itself}

\chapter{First}
\section{Alpha}
\section{Beta}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Gamma}
\section{Epsilon}

\chapter{Third}
\section{Eins}
\section{Drei}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when I change the d\ocument class to article like this : from %\documentclass[pfe]{./tpl/isipfe}
documentclass[]{./tpl/isipfe}
\graphicspath{{./img/}} to documentclass[]{article}
 it shows error

Comment: @girl_of_data Careful, your comment is under the wrong answer. A quick search indicates that the isipfe class is provided by a university for a specific purpose. As such, you're probably not supposed to change it, and should stick to its stylistic choices. Also, this class is based on the `book` class, so section numbers without chapter numbers is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Miyase what I understand from you that I can't change the class

Comment: @girl_of_data Technically you can, if you know enough about LaTeX, but in this context, yes I encourage you to check whether you should. For instance, ask the teachers who provided the class. They may wish for a unified style for all students, in which case you shouldn't modify it.